# Picking a date out of a relational database php

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm creating a rollcall type of page.

I have a seemingly complex (It's probably not actually, I may be overthinking it) need in this database.

Here is my structure:

```
rollcall_teammates:
Lists all my users
-------------------------------------
| uniqueID | Name | LineID | Active |
-------------------------------------
|        1 |  Bob |      1 |      1 |
-------------------------------------
|        2 |  Sal |      2 |      1 |
-------------------------------------

rc_teammates_days:
The actual attendance of the users, the UserID is the uniqueID of my rollcall_teammates table.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| uniqueID | UserID | TimeIn | TimeOut |  Timestamp | hadLunch | Complete |   Status |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |      1 | 7:30AM |  4:00PM | 08/26/2016 |        1 |        0 | Attended |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        2 |      2 | 7:30AM |  4:00PM | 08/26/2016 |        1 |        0 | Attended |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

rc_teammates_jobs:
Jobs are not added for every single day, only when changed. The UserID is based off of rollcall_teammates aswell.
-----------------------------------------------
| uniqueID | UserID |        Job |  Timestamp |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 |      1 | Technician | 08/26/2016 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 |      2 | Technician | 08/26/2016 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

My problem is, for any inputted day I need a count of jobs that were active that day.

I was successful in doing this with the current date because it would always be the last job inputted into the job table.

This obviously isn't correct when looking at past dates

So what I need to do is get the closest recorded date (from the jobs database) that is on or before an inputted date.

The logic behind this, just thinking about it, is confusing me. So some help with that would be much appreciated. What I have currently is this:

This basically spits out a list of jobs active today (only works for current day) and counts them aswell.

```
$sql = "SELECT uniqueID,Name from rollcall_teammates WHERE $searchLines AND Active=1;";
$ret = $db->query($sql);

$jobsToday = array();
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){

    $attend = $db->querySingle("SELECT Status from rc_teammates_days WHERE UserID='".$row['uniqueID']."' AND Timestamp='".date("m/d/Y")."' ORDER BY uniqueID DESC LIMIT 1;");
    if((!empty($attend)) && (strcmp($attend,"Incomplete") != 0)) {
        $job = $db->querySingle("SELECT Job from rc_teammates_jobs WHERE UserID='".$row['uniqueID']."' ORDER BY uniqueID DESC LIMIT 1;");
        if((strcmp($attend,"Attended") == 0) || (strcmp($attend,"In Late (BL)") == 0) || (strcmp($attend,"In After Lunch") == 0)) {
            array_push($jobsToday,$job);
        }
    }

}

$distinct = array_unique($jobsToday);
$counts = array_count_values($jobsToday);

echo "<ul>";
foreach($distinct as &$value) {
    echo "<li>$value (".$counts[$value].")</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: You can't. Your data doesn't actually track that information. Nowhere in this schema do you describe the relationship between an active job and a given date. If user 1 is active from the user table, but they have 3 jobs listed in the jobs table on a given date, how do you know which job is considered active for what date? There is no logical consistency.

Comment: @Sherif I just need the job listed closest on or before the given date.

Comment: I get what you _want_... The problem is your schema doesn't describe this relationship in any meaningful way. What happens if you have more than one job listed on that date? Which one is valid? What happens if you have none? The schema you defined simply doesn't support the question you want to ask.

Comment: @Sherif "job listed closest on or before the given date". The closest one is the valid one. If multiple exist, it would be the last one entered on that day (Which would be determined by the uniqueID). There will always be a job listed for the user.

Comment: @Sherif OR, how can I change my schema to work better for my needs?

Comment: My point was to demonstrate that your requirements are ambiguous. Ambiguous requirements are hard to satisfy in code and easily deceive the person behind the code. None of your assertions there are actually provably true. The word _closest_ doesn't mean anything in relational theory, because order does not matter. And no, your uniqueID doesn't determine what happened first or last. It also still fails to solve the requirement of what happens if there are __none__? We could go down this path of trying to clarify ambiguous requirements forever, but why not just fix your schema?

Comment: @Sherif Do you have any suggestions on how I could remodel my schema?

Comment: Suggestions are hard to come by when you provide an incomplete picture of the problem. Any suggestions I do provide at this point are going to be arbitrary guesses of me filling in the holes you've left, to try and complete the picture. This is likely to create more back-and-forth than is typically suited for a format like StackOverflow, which qualifies the question as __too broad__.

Comment: My best suggestion right now would be to break up your job entity into two tables so that you can actually normalize your data. One table describes the job itself. And the other table is used to describe the relationship between the job and the user. This way you can actually identify on what date a job was taken by what users.